# how to clone a directory list to another directory

Tags: linux, bash, cat

I am trying clone a directory and it's subdirectories into another directory. I have hundreds of music directories with sub-directories that I want to convert from flac to ogg. I want all the music Subdirectories under /Music to be cloned to /Music/Oggs/ so that when I do the conversion the files will all be written to the same directory names.
Here's what I have:

/Music/Van_Halen_Discography/1980 Women And Children First/

What I need is the clone of directories to this:

/Music/Oggs/Van_Halen_Discography/1980 Women And Children First/

I tried using,  'find /Music -type d |cat > /Music/Oggs'

But it didn't work, what am I missing?
Thanks

Comment: `cat` does not make directories. It just creates a text file /Music/Oggs in the given command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use rsync as follows.

```
 rsync -av -f"+ */" -f"- *" /path/to/Music/ /path/to/Music/oggs
```

Here `-a` tells rsync to recurse through dirs and preserve links, permissions and ownership while `v` makes it verbose. `-f` is a filter with the first argument including all directories and the second excluding all files. I suggest trying out on a small example first if you are unfamiliar with rsync.

Comment: This worked but it made the directory /Music/Oggs/Music/ then music Sub-directories, which is fine, I just went into /Music/Oggs/Music and did a 'mv * ../'  I got what I needed, Thanks

Comment: The first path should have been `/path/to/Music/` with the ending slash. My bad. Glad you worked it out.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way, let's suppose you are in `~/Music/` with the current shell.

```
mkdir Oggs            # In case you do not have done before    
cp -rp !(Oggs) Oggs
```

- `cp` is the normal command used in Linux to copy files and directories
- `-rp` or if you prefer `-r` `-p` are options to  `r`ecurse through directories and to   `p`reserve time accesses, ownerships ...
  Use `man cp` for a more complete insight.
- `!(Oggs)` *Tricky* with `!` you **negate** what is inside the parenthesis: so you are telling copy all file and not `Oggs` to `Oggs`

Note : This requires `shopt extglob` on, if is disabled use `shopt -s extglob` to enabled it.